# Transformation From One XML to Another XML Format Using JAXB in Apache Camel Route without using XSLT

Tags: apache-camel, marshalling, unmarshalling, spring-dsl

I have request xml which is consumed by target system. Target system accpets XML but format is different.So I need to build marshal and unmarshal logic to get data flowing in my route to Target System. So is there any way where I can achive using Java bean approach or jAXB without using dozer or XSLT

Apache Camel with Springboot

Comment: I guess you could have two classes with the relevant JAXB annotations `SourceClass` and `TargetClass`, and map the data from one class to another as a SourceClass method such as `TargetClass sourceObject.toTargetClass()`, or define a class that implements TypeConverters interface and register it in the Camel Context. However, if I'm mapping XML to XML I'd always use XSLT2 as it is very flexible and economical with code.

Comment: XSLT will be easier and more flexible than using pojo  to pojo mapping

Comment: @Screwtape Thanks !!!Could you please provide any example for same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very quick and simple way to do an XSLT transformation.

Assuming your source data looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <elem1 id="1">
    <child1>Hello</child1>
    <child2>World</child2>
  </elem1>
</root>
```

you can have a transform XSLT file that looks a bit like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="elem1">
    <div>
      <h1>Section <xsl:value-of select="@id" /></h1>
      <p><xsl:value-of select="child1" /></p>
      <p><xsl:value-of select="child2" /></p>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()"> <!-- identity transform -->
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

so you then pass this via the camel xslt transform, one way or another, for example

```
from("direct:start")
  .to("xslt:myTransformFile.xsl&saxon=true")
  .to("direct:end")
```

you should then end up with the following XML message being passed to `direct:end`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <div>
    <h1>Section 1</h1>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>World</p>
  </div>
</root>
```

because the identity template has copied any elements that are not matched by another template, and the template replaces any element that match the selection criteria, with the contents of the template. In this case `elem1` is replaced, by the contents of the template. The `<xsl:value-of ... />` elements are interpreted but any element that doesn't begin `<xsl:...` is just part of the output.

For a simple introduction to XSLT, you can look here: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_intro.asp.

Comment: I will try these option and hopefully it should work.

Comment: this actually helped me to understand how xslt transformation works.. thanks